# Vtiger 7 install on QNAP with PHP 7

Tags: php, vtiger, qnap

Hello I have problem with QNAP server.
I have to install and configuration Vtiger 7 on this server. On server is installed PHP 7.3.7, but the recommended version for Vtiger 7 is PHP 5.4.2.

If I install and configure Vtiger 7 then the installation is break without error message.

I think thie difrent to both version is the reason, and yes I check to login information to database is correct.
So how to install older version PHP in QNAP server, and is it possible to do without physical contact with server and without ftp?

detailed information:

- Serwer: **QNAP**
- System: **QTS**
- System version: **4.5.2.1594**
- PHP recommended version: **5.4.2**
- PHP present version: **7.3.7**
- Vtiger version: **7.1.0.1**

I will happy and grateful for answer :)

Comment: What is your exact vtiger version? 7.1, 7.2, 7.3? You should be able to use php 7.3 or 7.2 with vtiger 7.2 or 7.3. Any vtiger 7.x version won't work with php 5.4, that's for sure.

Comment: My version Vtiger is 7.1.0.1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solution problem.

The reason problem it is I'm don't swich on network TCP/IP for SQL Server.

If anyone would like install Vtiger 7 in QNAP server you have to do:

In setings php.ini you schuld set:

- `display_errors = On`
- `log_errors = Off`
- `error_reporting = E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED`

Remember you have to switch on server www and sql server with TCP/IP network.

Don't worry if you have, `NOT RECOMMENDED` next to error_reporting in present settings. It isn't problem.

About PHP version it is not important. Only you have to have 5.4.2 or news.

!! IMPORTANT !!

I recommend that you pay attention to the comments.

Comment: I'd downvoting because php 5.4 won't work for vtiger 7

Comment: I followed the recommended settings vtiger 7 gave me during the installation

Comment: I think the recommended configuration requires at least php 5.4, but thst's still wrong. If you try using  php 5.4, you'll see it won't work.